# How can I get SSHFS to work?

Tags: ssh

I am hosting a web server on my Raspberry Pi and I'd like to be able to edit the hosted files through sshfs on my MacBook. I have installed sshfs on my Pi and MacBook and have also installed FUSE for macOS on my MacBook.

The files on the web server are owned by www-data so that web users can interact with the site.

I have tried these commands on the Pi:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G pi www-data
$ sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

And these on my MacBook:

```
$ sshfs pi@bbqpi.local:/var/www/html/ "/Users/me/Documents/Raspberry Pi/pimount"
$ sshfs pi@bbqpi.local:/var/www/html/ "/Users/me/Documents/Raspberry Pi/pimount" -o defer_permissions,allow_other
```

But each time I can mount the folder, open the files, but if I try to save any changes I get "Permission denied." How can I save changes to files that I am mounting through sshfs?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if I try this on my system group 33 `www-data` on the pi displays as `_appstore` on the Mac. `sshfs` normally maps UID/GID to the logged user i.e. `pi`

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had a command parameter backwards. The first command should be this instead:

`$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data pi`